# DocuSign Email Resource File Not Updating

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We're already using a custom email resource file. I updated the text for outgoing emails and the email message is not displaying the new text. When I check the resource file it's there. The original customization is displaying in the email message but the couple of added sentences are not.

Comment: are you doing this through saelsforce? via the API?

Comment: Mention the technologies you are using and paste the code to understand the problem.